# Prove $S_{n} \cap [1,k] = S \cap [1,k]$ eventually

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $S_{n} \in \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ be such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, S_{n} \subset S_{n+1}$.  Let $S = \cup^{\infty}_{n=1} S_{n}$.

Prove that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_{n} \cap [1,k] = S \cap [1,k]$ for sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you prove it for $k=1$?

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a **[homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)**, please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of proof : Show that for any $i\in [1,k]$,  there is a $N_i$
such that $S_{N_i}\cap \lbrace i \rbrace=S\cap \lbrace i \rbrace$.
Then ,show that $N={\textsf{max}(N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_k)}$ works.

Comment: But how? Since $S_{n_{i}} \in \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$, I can extend $S_{n_{i}}$ indefinitely without including $i$.

Comment: @Zach What do you mean ? The condition $S_{N_i}\cap \lbrace i \rbrace=S\cap \lbrace i \rbrace$ fixes it all. If $i$ is in $S$, it will be in $S_{n_i}$ also and you cannot add it a second time. If $i$ is not in $S$, you are prohibited from adding $i$ by definition.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. I just thought that since I'm given the $S_{n}$'s, I'm not allowed to define them. But this isn't really defining them. Do I need to prove that $N_{i}$ exists or does it result directly from the fact that $i \in S$?

Comment: @Zach You do have to prove that $N_i$ exists, and you must distinguish two cases : $i\in S$ and $i\not\in S$.